# Is there any difference between "so" and "then" in these two examples? Would they be equally natural?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, idiomatic-language

Dialog 1:

A - *Don't you want to meet her?*

B - *Yes, but--*

A - ***So**/**Then** go over there.*

Dialog 2:

A - *Didn't I just tell you to stay out of this?*

B - *Yes, but--*

A - ***So**/**Then** what the hell are you doing?*

Hi, all. Is there any small difference between "so" and "then" in the two examples above? Would they be equally natural to use in both examples?

Comment: Generally speaking, *then* is used with two people talking, or as two sentences, like you have demonstrated above. (Example: "You wanted to meet her?  Then go over there." - It assumes an empty response, from the other person, between the sentences.)  *So* would be used more frequently with a single speaker like: "You wanted to meet her, so you should go over there."

Comment: When used before an imperative, ***so*** and ***then*** are near-synonymous (they both mean ***Therefore, In that case, Consequently, Hence,...***). Purely a personal opinion, but I feel that ***so*** is potentially a bit more "blunt, dismissive, confrontational" in such contexts. They're *both* potentially "rude", anyway - but that's no problem in the cited context, where the speaker is obviously "talking down" to the addressee.

Answer (score 1):

In these sorts of applications, both "so" and "then" can be used interchangeably, and mean more or less the same thing.

Personally, to my ear, there is a slightly different nuance between them, but it is not anything very large or significant:

- "Then" has a little bit more of the feeling of a logical appeal.  That is, it suggests "*You should realize for yourself* (if you think about it) that this follows from the previous thing"
- "So" has slightly more of the feeling of pushing your own decision on the other person.  That is, it suggests "*I have decided* that this follows from the previous thing"

But many people may not even make this distinction themselves, and may not see any difference between them..